# Find categorial column with the highest average(mean) of a specified numeric column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
def category_with_highest_average(df, cat_column, num_column):
    solution = df.groupby(cat_column).mean().sort_values(by=[num_column])
    solution = solution.tail(1)
    return solution
test_case = category_with_highest_average(price_city_df, 'city', 'price')
```

I have tried above code for the solution. I'm getting output as
price
city
Delhi   1620.5

Expected Output :

Delhi

I'm not sure how i can fetch only city name. Please help

Comment: try `return solution['city']` or `return solution.loc[:,'city']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will suffice to just do:

```py
return df[[cat_column, num_column]].groupby(cat_column).mean().idxmax()
```

Comment: @user9185088, consider upvoting the accepted answer as well :)